# How do I define targets in DHIS 2?

Tags: dhis2

How can I define and capture targets in DHIS 2? There does not seem to be specific meta-data configuration or a specific object for this. Is there a way to model targets using one of the existing objects in DHIS 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DHIS 2 does not have a specific mechanism for targets. Instead, a viable approach is to utilize regular data elements to capture targets. When you think of it, targets are very similar to data elements in nature - you would typically like to capture them for a time period, a data element and an organisational unit. Creating targets by using regular data elements are explained in this tutorial:

https://www.dhis2.org/setting-up-targets